# Как присвоить значение по default, если пользователь ничего не ввел?

Tags: dart

Читал, что `??` присваивает значение если левая часть является `null`, если кто сможет объяснить что такое `null` буду признателен.

```dart
stdout.write("Введите ваше имя: ");
final String userName = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "user";// как вот тут присвоить значение если пользователь ничего не ввел

print(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Значение `null` обозначает, что у переменной **отсутствует значение**.

Понимать это надо в весьма широком смысле и отсутствие значения может иметь разный смысл для разных объектов.

В Dart при объявлении переменной всегда явно указывается - может ли эта переменная принимать значение `null`. Например:

```dart
String userName; // значение может быть только String
String? userPass; // значение может быть String или null
```

Вы объявили переменную как `String`, а значит она не может стать равной `null`, но функция `stdin.readLineSync()` возвращает тип `String?`, то есть она может вернуть `null` и Вы должны в своей программе предусмотреть это.

Например, можно проверить возвращаемое значение в условном операторе:

```dart
String userName;
String? input = stdin.readLineSync();
if (input==null){
  userName = 'default name';
} else {
  userName = input;
}
```

Или другой вариант с использованием тернарного оператора:

```dart
userName = input==null ? 'default name' : input;
```

Но самым красивым вариантом решения является оператор `??`, который обозначает, что если значение переменной равно `null`, то вернуть значение, которое находится справа от `??`, в противном случае вернуть значение самой переменной.

```dart
userName = input ?? 'default name';
// либо без переменной input
userName = stdin.readLineSync() ?? 'default name';
```

Все три рассмотренных варианта идентичны по смыслу.